# multiple notifications with Notifications API Continuously in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, notifications

I want Show message multiple times and one after another continuously and for this matter i use Notifications API, When i run my code in chrome browser everything is good But when i run my code in firefox when i use one notification constructor every thing is good and with multiple notification nothing show at all !

In code:

```
var options= {
   body: 'test1'
};
new window.Notification('subj', options);
```

This is good in chrome and firefox, but this:

```
var options= {
   body: 'test1'
};
new window.Notification('subj', options);
new window.Notification('subj', options);
new window.Notification('subj', options);
```

show three message in chrome and none in firefox.

Why firefox can not show all notification like chrome ?

Is there any other way to show notification on client desktop that works perfectly in all browsers ?

Answer (score 3):

My temporary solution which is not very nice, but it works:

```
new Notification('a');
setTimeout(function() {
    new Notification('b');
}, 200);
```

In my Firefox, the timeout with 30ms works fine, with 20ms nothing happens. So I now use 200ms to have a little buffer because I don't know, how other Browsers will behave...

Comment: Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: If i know a right way to do this, I didn't ask a question in stack !! :)